# creating a bootable USB stick on Mac OS

Tags: dual-boot, usb, software-installation, mac

So, I'm really excited to get my hands on my first Linux system. I did all the steps required for downloading Ubuntu, until the step with creating a bootable USB stick, wher eI have a problem.

I followed the steps in the link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx
and I arrived at step 8, where it says:

> Execute sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m

Here is what I typed in:

> sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m

after waiting for 3 minutes and a half (or 210.289801 seconds) of data transfer (of 1008730112 bytes) I get a window with the message:

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer

with options to: "Initialize...", "Ignore", or "Eject"

Q: How do I solve this problem? (Bonus: Where did all the data go?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, and it seems like the only solution on the whole internet (I've suffered).

Apparently this problem has occured with tons of people, but I've only found one solution. One person took it upon himself to solve it.

Use http://penguintosh.com/ You'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If u have an iso, try converting it into UDRW format. The following command will help u convert:-

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o destination_file.img source_file.iso
```

U will get a .img.dmg

Then, clear all the data on your USB device and copy the image to the USB stick.
later, try this

```
$ dd if=destination_file.img.dmg of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

wait till it completes and then eject using,

```
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The first step I have done, since it's in the link I mentioned.. but what do you mean by "$" in your comment?

Comment: oh don't worry about that, u don't have to consider "$". u type just the rest of the command :) for instance, when you open a terminal, you start typing in front of "xyz$", so thats what $ about

Comment: Anyways.. That didn't seem to work. First dd doesn't work on it's own, it only works when ai put sudo before it. Secondly, i was using the same command with if=location/of/file/in/downloads.img.dmg but since u mentioned that i should put the file in the USB, i guessed you meant if=location/in/disk. Well the sudo dd command doesn't work if the disk is not unmounted, and when I unmount it, the file in the USB cannot be read. So i can't follow the steps you mentioned